# Laravel nova multiselect edit not working

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-nova

I'm using laravel nova for creating an admin panel. This is my code.

Laravel nova resource,

```
use Nova\Multiselect\Multiselect;

public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),            
            Multiselect::make(__('Day'),'day')
                ->options($this->getweedkDay()),
        ];
    }

private function getweedkDay(){
        $weekDay = [];

        $weekDay[1] = __('Sunday');
        $weekDay[2] = __('Monday');
        $weekDay[3] = __('Tuesday');
        $weekDay[4] = __('Wednesday');
        $weekDay[5] = __('Thursday');
        $weekDay[6] = __('Friday');
        $weekDay[7] = __('Saturday');


        return $weekDay;
    }
```

I'm using this [plugin](https://github.com/arku31/NovaMultiSelect) for multi select and date field is a varchar field in database. The issue is **even I can select items and save them in db they will not be able to see in edit view or index view for nova resource**. it would be great if someone can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this package instead it's more mature and maintained as well:

https://github.com/optimistdigital/nova-multiselect-field

Comment: thnks for help bro

Comment: @vlmuth Please mark my answer as the correct answer if you feel it was.